# rendering an image within c# & sharpdx dirext3d9 [game overlay]

Tags: directx, directx9, sharpdx, overlay

I'm following this [guide](https://github.com/spazzarama/Direct3DHook) and the related [blog post](http://spazzarama.com/2011/03/14/c-screen-capture-and-overlays-for-direct3d-9-10-and-11-using-api-hooks/) to implement a basic game overlay for DirectX 9 games using SharpDX.

So the tutorial already have an example for text rendering but I need to be also able to render a provided image to the overlay.

Any ideas, guides?

Answer (score 1):

For DirectX 9 you can use a texture and a sprite. In DXHookD3D9.cs you could do something like the following in "DoCaptureRenderTarget". Don't create the resources each frame but for simplicity here it is all together.

```
// Create resources
SharpDX.Direct3D9.Texture tex = null;
Sprite sprite = null;
tex = SharpDX.Direct3D9.Texture.FromFile(device, filename);
sprite = new SharpDX.Direct3D9.Sprite(device);
// to resize/rotate/position sprite.Transform = some 4x4 affine transform matrix (SharpDX.Matrix)

sprite.Begin(SharpDX.Direct3D9.SpriteFlags.None);
SharpDX.Vector3 pos = new SharpDX.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
SharpDX.Color color = new SharpDX.ColorBGRA(0xffffffff);

sprite.Draw(tex, color, null, null, pos);

// Finish drawing
sprite.End();
```